# Cannot initialize disk in PowerShell : Initialize-Disk throws "The disk has already been initialized"

Tags: powershell, partition, hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I'm trying to change the flash drive's partition style to GPT using PowerShell, but the cmdlet throws "The disk has already been initialized" (even though I've cleaned the drive):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Clear-Disk 5 -RemoveData -RemoveOEM

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Disk 5

Number Friendly Name                            OperationalStatus                          Total Size Partition Style          
------ -------------                            -----------------                          ---------- ---------------          
5      UFD 2.0 Silicon-Power16G USB Device      Online                                       15.14 GB MBR     

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Initialize-Disk 5 -PartitionStyle GPT
Initialize-Disk : The disk has already been initialized.
At line:1 char:1
+ Initialize-Disk 5 -PartitionStyle GPT
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk) [Initialize-Disk], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 41001,Initialize-Disk
```

How can I de-initialize the disk so that I can re-initialize it?

P.S. `-PartitionStyle MBR` shows the same error.

Comment: It looks like the Clear-Disk cmdlet is not working as it should or the drive is not properly clearing the data as the drive should revert back to a partition style of RAW after it is run. Do you have this issue with other storage as well?

Comment: I see this with two different models of USB drives as well. If I try the diskpart equivalent (select disk and then clean), the drive becomes MBR instead. Wondering if USB drives can't be raw...

Comment: I was running into the same issue. I searched and found this [Microsoft Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-an-mbr-disk-into-a-gpt-disk) that states, "You cannot use the GPT partition style on removable media."

Answer (score 0):

`Clear-Disk` does not uninitialize removable media, only disks (HDD, SSD, VHD, etc.). To change the partition style of a removable medium, you can use [`Set-Disk`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-disk) with the `-PartitionStyle` parameter:

```
Set-Disk -Number 5 -PartitionStyle MBR
```

To view an example on how you can use `Set-Disk` inside a pipeline, you can have a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68981701/11942268) on SO.